# Loading certificate files from file

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, x509certificate2

For an Azure web-service I need to load a `.pfx` file. This I can do from file (installed next to the service). To get everything working I need to install a `.cer` and a `.crl` into the trusted certificate store. My question is: can this be avoided? Is there a way to load and use these two files from file?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/11/programmatically-installing-and-using-your-management-certificate-with-the-new-publishsettings-file/

Comment: Very nice link, but is there a way to use those files WITHOUT having to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not wish to answer my own question, but the answer appears to be that it is not possible, and you have to install the files.

I have not found a way to use my files, other than to install them into the local certificate store. For this a command line tool has been written that installs them when the worker role starts.

If somebody can prove me wrong, I'll happily reopen this question.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-create-a-x509-certificate-for-sql-azure-database-management-api.aspx :

When you make an API call, you can use the .cer file instead of .pfx file if the associated certificate is installed in the local certificate store.  When the .cer is added into the webrequest, CLR will automatically search for the associated pfx in the local certificate store.  If the certificate exists, then call will go through, otherwise, it will fail.  You can use an arbitrary value for the password.  However it is not an requirement to import the certificate to the local certificate store.  If the certificate is not in the local certificate store, you much provide the associated .pfx file with the correct password for the .pfx file.

Comment: I do load the `.pfx` from file now, but I still need the `.cer` and `.crl` in my certificate store, or my API call will fail. So just loading the `.pfx` is not enough in my case.